# How do I add line breaks when using the Thymeleaf template layout?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How do I add line breaks when using the Thymeleaf template layout?

Here is my html base code.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="common_header(title,links)">
<title th:replace="${title}">Layout title</title>
<!-- Common -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/
awesomeapp.css}">
<link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{/images/favicon.ico}">
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/sh/scripts/codebase.js}"></
script>
<!-- Add -->
<th:block th:replace="${links}" />
</head>
```

And this is the html main code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="template/layout/base :: common_header(~{::title},~{::link})">
<title>Main title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css}">
</head>
<body>
main content
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result rendered by `<th:block th:replace="${links}" />`.

`<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"><link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui .css}">`

But what I want is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css}">
```

Making the line break like this is what I want.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you considered using [Thymeleaf Layout Dialect](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect)? It is probably easier to get what you want here with that.